# map a vector of characters to lm formula in r

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to make a list of lm object using purrr::map.
use mtcars as an example:

```
vars <- c('hp', 'wt', 'disp')
map(vars, ~lm(mpg~.x, data=mtcars))
```

error:
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ .x, data = mtcars, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for '.x')

I also tried:

```
map(vars, function(x) {x=sym(x); lm(mpg~!!x, data=mtcars)})
```

I got error message:

```
Error in !x : invalid argument type
```

Can anyone tell what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `map(vars, ~ lm(paste("mpg ~", .x), data=mtcars) )` ? I'm not a purrr user, so I am guessing, but I think you need to pass in `.x` as a character so it can be translated to a `formula` so `lm` can interpret it. This is analogous to the base R approach `Map(function(x) lm(paste("mpg ~", x), data=mtcars), vars)`

Comment: Another with base R's `reformulate` and `lapply` is `lapply(vars, function(vars) lm(reformulate(vars, "mpg"), mtcars))`.

Answer (score 11):

The usual way is to `paste` together formulas as strings, convert them by `map`ping `as.formula` (you can't make a vector of formulas; it has to be a list), and then `map` `lm`. You can combine it all to a single call if you like, but I've come to prefer mapping single functions, which makes code easier to read:

```r
library(purrr)

c('hp', 'wt', 'disp') %>% 
    paste('mpg ~', .) %>% 
    map(as.formula) %>% 
    map(lm, data = mtcars)
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> .f(formula = .x[[i]], data = ..1)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    30.09886     -0.06823  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> .f(formula = .x[[i]], data = ..1)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           wt  
#>      37.285       -5.344  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> .f(formula = .x[[i]], data = ..1)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp  
#>    29.59985     -0.04122
```

It's actually unnecessary to call `map(as.formula)` as `lm` will coerce it into a formula, but not all models are so generous (e.g. `mgcv::gam`).

A downside of this approach are that the call listed in the object looks funky, but the coefficients tell you which is which easily enough anyway. A useful alternative is to keep the formula as a string in one column of a data.frame and the model in a list column, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(formula = paste('mpg ~', c('hp', 'wt', 'disp')), 
           model = map(formula, lm, data = mtcars))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      formula    model
#>        <chr>   <list>
#> 1   mpg ~ hp <S3: lm>
#> 2   mpg ~ wt <S3: lm>
#> 3 mpg ~ disp <S3: lm>
```

Comment: A pity that the output list isn't named via the input as per `Map`. That would make it easy to do `output["hp"]` for instance. Though the `data_frame` solution is quite neat.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah, you could use `set_names`, but to keep the names from getting stripped by `paste` you have to use the somewhat clunky `c('hp', 'wt', 'disp') %>% 
    set_names(paste('mpg ~', .), .) %>% 
    map(as.formula) %>% 
    map(lm, data = mtcars)`, at which point the base R looks pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant tidyverse approach demonstrated by @alistaire worked well for me until I tried to pass the list column to the `stargazer` package and received "% Error: Unrecognized object type."

In case it is helpful for anyone else trying to use `purrr` `map` and `stargazer`, this slight modification solved the issue:

```
models_out <- data_frame(
    formula = paste('mpg ~', c('hp', 'wt', 'disp')), 
    model = map(
                .x = formula, 
                .f = function(x) lm(x, data = mtcars))
                )

stargazer(models_out$model, type = 'text')

===========================================================
                                   Dependent variable:     
                              -----------------------------
                                           mpg             
                                 (1)       (2)       (3)   
-----------------------------------------------------------
hp                            -0.068***                    
                               (0.010)                     
                                                           
wt                                      -5.344***          
                                         (0.559)           
                                                           
disp                                              -0.041***
                                                   (0.005) 
                                                           
Constant                      30.099*** 37.285*** 29.600***
                               (1.634)   (1.878)   (1.230) 
                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                     32        32        32    
R2                              0.602     0.753     0.718  
Adjusted R2                     0.589     0.745     0.709  
Residual Std. Error (df = 30)   3.863     3.046     3.251  
F Statistic (df = 1; 30)      45.460*** 91.375*** 76.513***
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```