# Seeing underlying objects in purrr::map call

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a character vector of dependent variable names that is used by repeated regression calls approximately like so:

```
library(purrr)
c('hp', 'wt', 'disp') %>% 
    paste('mpg ~', .) %>% 
    map(as.formula) %>% 
    map(lm, data = mtcars)
```

The sequence to convert to a formula comes from alistaire's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45852633/5623577). However, using `map` as a a way to repeat the call on multiple variables masks the variable names from the summary output:

```
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> .f(formula = .x[[i]], data = ..1)       <- This is what I'm talking about
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    30.09886     -0.06823
#> ...
```

When I use the `~` syntax it is a little more clear because it shows the data frame name:

```
    ...
    map(., ~lm(.x, data = mtcars))

#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = .x, data = mtcars)         <- A little better
#> ...
```

**Is there a way to expose the underlying `.x` variable contents in the `map` call so that the summary output is more transparent?** For example, I'm hoping for something like the typical `lm` call outputs, `lm(formulua = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)`.

Comment: Might be better off `nest`ing and `map`ping in my opinion.

Comment: I think it is the issue with the `Call`.  You can always update the Call

Comment: You can use `map(c('hp', 'wt', 'disp'), ~ reformulate(.x, response = "mpg") %>% lm(data = mtcars))`

Comment: @akrun the `reformulate` approach has the same problem in the call. The output is `lm(formula = ., data = mtcars)`.

Comment: You said `lm(formula = .x, data = mtcars)`  is better.  So, I didn't know what you expected

Comment: @akrun It at least showed the data frame being referenced, but not the call. In my actual application I'm using `map2` with `.x` as the formula and `.y` as different data frames, but that is that the output shows.

Comment: If you want to get the correct formula, try `map(c('hp', 'wt', 'disp'), ~ reformulate(.x, response = "mpg") %>%
                                {fml <- .;
        lm1 <- lm(.,  data = mtcars);
         lm1$call <- fml;
         lm1})`

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `call` in `lm` is an option

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(c('hp', 'wt', 'disp'), ~ reformulate(.x, response = "mpg") %>% {
                             fml <- .
                             lm1 <- lm(.,  data = mtcars)
                             lm1$call <- fml
                             lm1
        })
```